# How to change gui font size in JavaFX SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx, netbeans-7, font-size, scenebuilder

I just want to know how change gui font size in JavaFX SceneBuilder (on my screen it's just too small and it doesn't get default environment font size). There is no item like font size in preferences, so I thought about some java parameters or properties. Or maybe we could override some css. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about the default font size used for the tool itself (e.g. it's menu items, etc) or are you asking about the default font size for a UI you are designing using Scene Builder?

Comment: @jewelsea, I'm asking about tool itself (SceneBuilder). It's unusable in my environment cause of tiny font size.

Comment: Create a [feature request against the DTL project](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL).

Comment: I changed it for Netbeans by going into the .config file and adding in a key-value pair. I wonder if theres something similar for the scene builder.

Comment: For Netbeans they use this http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize the only file I could find that looks like the equivalent was scenebuilder.properties but I don't know what to add as the key value pair.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to edit the scenebuilder jar file directly.
On the windows platform go into C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\app\scenebuilder-11.0.0-all.jar\com\oracle\javafx\scenebuilder\kit\css, and modified the ThemeDefault.css file.

For example, to change the default font for the controls property sheet:

```
.property-sheet {
    -fx-font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

There are lots of other properties in there which control the ui.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for the hint. I changed all fonts to size 1.2em in file ThemeDefault.css. And I changed the selection color: -sb-selected-bar-color: rgb(201, 222, 234);
Now the SceneBuilder looks better.
I did the changes using 7-zip. Here you can edit inside a .jar.

Answer (score -1):

Use css, its better. Something like this
-fx-font-size:20;
Specify id for the gui control you want to change its font in the scene builder's properties section and use it for the css.

Comment: I`m not one who minus you, but I was asking about font size in tool (SceneBuilder) itself, not how to do it in JavaFX.